# if value is null get previous value sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have table that looks like this

```
Id Description
5  Null
4  This is a description
3  This is a description
2  Null
1  Null
```

I need to create an update statement that will update the null value if the previous value is not null.

```
Id Description
5  This is a description
4  This is a description
3  This is a description
2  Null
1  Null
```

Any advice or assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
update toupdate
set description = updateto.description 
from yourtable toupdate
  join yourtable updateto on updateto.id = toupdate.id - 1
where updateto.description is not null
  and toupdate.description is null;
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4a8a0/1)

This produces the following results:

```
ID  DESCRIPTION
5   This is a description
4   This is a description
3   This is a description
2   (null)
1   (null)
```

*EDIT: As pointed out by comment by Aaron Bertrand.*

If your IDs aren't consecutive, you can use the `row_number()` function to join on instead of the ids:

```
with cte as (
    select *, row_number() over (order by (select null)) rn
    from yourtable
  )
update toupdate
set description = updateto.description 
from cte toupdate
  join cte updateto on toupdate.rn = updateto.rn - 1
where updateto.description is not null
  and toupdate.description is null;
```

You can change your order by criteria as needed.

[Updated SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cb9af/1)

Comment: @AaronBertrand -- Great point -- and if that is true, then using ROW_NUMBER() will be the other option.  Just need OP to verify sort order (although it appear to be ID Desc).  Thanks!

Comment: @AaronBertrand -- edited the answer to include the option to use ROW_NUMBER() -- kind regards.

Comment: Cheers, much better. :-) Though may still want to order by the id column rather than the undefined `SELECT NULL` - it will still work for ordering even if there are gaps.

Comment: @user2234168 -- np, glad we could help!

Answer (score 1):

The most common way (that I am aware of) to do this sort of thing is with a self-join:

```
-- WARNING: Untested Code
UPDATE YourTable
SET Origin.Description = Proxy.Description
FROM YourTable Origin
JOIN YourTable Proxy
    ON Origin.Id = Proxy.Id - 1
WHERE Origin.Description IS NULL
AND Proxy.Description IS NOT NULL
```

This will join `YourTable` to itself so that one row looks like this:

```
Origin.Id | Origin.Description | Proxy.Id | Proxy.Description
------------------------------------------------------------------
        5 |               NULL |        4 | This is a description
```

**EDIT**
If you are not guaranteed always incrementing IDs then you will want to use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
;WITH NumberedRows
AS
    (
    SELECT *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id) AS [Row #]
     FROM YourTable
     )
SELECT *
FROM NumberedRows Origin
JOIN NumberedRows Proxy
    ON Origin.Id = Proxy.Id - 1
WHERE Origin.Description IS NULL
AND Proxy.Description IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: This relies on contiguous values in the `Id` column. What if there are gaps? What if the OP wants to update more than one row above the last row with a non-NULL value?